# How to sort an array in a unique order

Tags: javascript

Given an array:

```
var myList = [ 'Normal', 'Urgent', 'Alert', 'Casual', 'Follow up' ];
```

I want to output this list in say, a dropdown. I want '*Urgent*' to show up first, followed by '*Alert*'. The rest should be sorted alphabetically.

I'm aware I can alphabetically sort the entire array with `myList.sort()` but is there a way to sort this list to my unique requirements? I'm hoping this can be done as an array without converting it to an object and assigning priority identifiers - but I may be wrong.

Also, what if Urgent or Alert doesn't exist?

**EDIT**: Here is what I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/reala/rqacrz0k/

Comment: My question says I tried myList.sort(), maybe I wrote it in Spanish

Comment: You're going to need a sort comparator function that uses an alternative sort key for things you need to sort in other than the normal order.

Comment: @bruh In solving this issue. What have you tried solving the current problem, ie writing a function to do what you want?

Comment: Mr @AndrewLi please see updated post, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object for the sort order.

```js
var array = [ 'Normal', 'Urgent', 'Alert', 'Casual', 'Follow up' ];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var order = { Urgent: -2, Alert: -1 };
    return (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0) || a.localeCompare(b);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Nice solution! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's best if you keep your prioritized elements separate from the main list, if you can't guarantee they will be present. I would filter those elements out, sort the rest, and concatenate the results with your special list.

```js
var special = ["Urgent","Alert"];
var myList = [ 'Normal', 'Urgent', 'Alert', 'Casual', 'Follow up' ];

myList = special.concat(myList.filter(function(el){ return special.indexOf(el) == -1; }).sort());
 
alert(myList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter to get the special values, sort the rest, and concatenate the parts:

```js
var myList = [ 'Normal', 'Urgent', 'Alert', 'Casual', 'Follow up' ];

myList = myList.filter( v => v === 'Urgent' ).concat(
            myList.filter( v => v === 'Alert' ),
            myList.filter( v => !['Alert','Urgent'].includes(v) ).sort());

console.log(myList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myList = [ 'Normal', 'Urgent', 'Alert', 'Casual', 'Follow up' ];

console.log(['Urgent', 'Alert', ...myList.filter(item => item !== 'Urgent' && item !== 'Alert').sort()]);
```